# What is the best 3rd party GUI framework for application development in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

Examples could be Infragistics or DevExpress.

But I'm also looking for your opinions on other frameworks. It could even be WPF if that is your favorite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infragistics is very good. I think they have a better product for windows than the web. However, I get very upset using their products sometimes. I just want to find some hidden property, and it is impossible to find. They have way to many properties. Sure, you can do anything with their grid, but it should be easier. All of these vendors are leap frogging each other. You really have to compare all of them every year or two. I am currently using Infragistics on most web and windows project. If I could switch today, I would go to DevExpress for Web and Windows. Everything that Mark Miller and the guys at DevExpress produce is beautiful, and thoughtful.  On a side point, you should check out CodeRush and Refacter. I may sound like a salesman, but I am not. I just could no longer code without CodeRush. It would feel like coding with one hand. If you are going to spend $1000 or more on a framework, you should also get CodeRush.

Answer (score 3):

I've used Telerik RAD Controls for Asp.Net and it is a very comprehensive suite of controls that are easily converted to AJAX.  The support is top notch, with the forum as a first place to go to for research before contacting the staff.

The client side API is fairly easy to understand, and they have good examples of mixed implementations with client and server side code.

Comment: Looks very nice. I will have a look at their trial.

Answer (score 1):

I would say [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it before, but I've heard good things about [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/). My experience with the Infragistics Web components has been less than stellar. I found there were a lot of hidden features that I required, which were undocumented and had to go hunt around in the sample code for examples.

These toolkits can make sense for intranet applications but when you start providing it out on the web, the functionality can come at the cost of a bigger download for users. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

What frameworks are you looking for? I currently use Janus Grids for grids on the winform side, but DevExpress has an awesome web grid that is amazing.

Comment: I'm looking for application frameworks. Do you have any links on the Janus Grids?

Answer (score 0):

For current Winforms development my favorite is Infragistics. DevExpress seems to have more Silverlight controls in the works, but Infragistics may deliver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do much non-web development, but if I do I like to use gtk# for Mono ([screenshots](http://mono-project.com/Screenshots)). It's much more fun and very easy to program then winforms. WPF looks good to, but I only tried an Hello World.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics has got good controls for Applications. WinGrid is one of the most important ones which would help you displaying information professionally and is quick.

the only drawback is the time consuming process of contacting their helpdesk or searching for the hidden properties. But they do work after you get to know them !

Answer (score 0):

I would say go for DevExpress seems to be the most elegant, intuitive and well document suite out there.

To see their product offering in action demos.devexpress.com

Do the same for any component suite check out their demos and see which best suit you needs.